# How to to remove horizontal line from the modal body and footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**I want to remove horizontal lines from my modal**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a line above and below the content

Comment: which line do you want to remove. Can you create example code that we can run in fiddle or here

Comment: modal creates by default horizontal line before and after modal body. I want to remove these lines.

Comment: Remove `border-bottom` from `.modal-header` and `border-top` from `.modal-footer`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are talking about the borders applied to modal. Use the below code.

```
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}

.modal-footer {
    border-top: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Its been 2 years since this question was asked and I still don't see any answer with bootstrap so here it is, Just use the border-0 class in the header and footer div. That should do the trick.

```
<div class="modal-header border-0">
....
</div>

<div class="modal-footer border-0">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```
.no-border{
  border:none;
}
```

and simply add to your class

```
<div class="modal-header no-border">
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove these borders, I found it easiest to pass in a custom title component or string.

If you just want to remove the title altogether, set `title={null}` on  props. Then the title and its bottom border will not show. Note this does not remove the close "X" icon.

The same goes for the footer. Passing `footer={null}` as a prop to  removes it entirely (including the buttons). If you still want to show some content in the footer, there is a good example of using custom components in the Ant docs [here](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-footer)

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4.5: The modal-header and footer lines are just empty spaces in between.
Actuly, the modal-header and footer and body has no background color.
but when you change it, a separator lines shows up with white color, so we apply the the color to modal-content instead, just like this:

```
.modal-content
 background-color: red// this will hide the white separators
```

In some bootsrap version:
just add

```
.modal-footer
border: 0
.modal-header
border: 0
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:red;border: 0;">
      <div class="modal-header" style="border: 0;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="border: 0;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style='border: none;'>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style='border: none;'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/bz82oadf/
Thanks!!!!

Comment: This does not add anything to the existing answers, and doesn't bother to explain what it changes. Code-only answers are seldom useful.

Answer (score -1):

This helped me:

```
.modal-header {
border: none !important;
}

.modal-footer {
border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not add anything new to the existing answers.

Comment: Answer already exists and doesn't add anything new